# What are the units given to RecyclerView.OnScrollListener (dy,dx)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

According to the following documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html

You can add a listener to `RecyclerView` to be notified when the user scrolls.

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
```

What are the units for `int dx, int dy`, are they density independent `pixels (dp)`, `pixels (px)`? What are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pixels. Always assume pixels and convert to dp if needed.

See RecyclerView#dispatchOnScrolled:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/main/java/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java

Check the line 4723.

Comment: Does google have a github mirror? I always thought `googlesource.com` has barbaric UI

Comment: @AlanSTACK I agree. If I remember correctly it was here: https://github.com/android/platform_framework_support but the repo has been deleted or moved.

Comment: @AlanSTACK Perhaps it has moved here: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support

Answer (score 2):

> What are the units for int dx, int dy, are they density independent pixels (dp), pixels (px)? What are they?

- @param **`dx`** horizontal distance scrolled in **`pixels`**
- @param **`dy`** vertical distance scrolled in **`pixels`**

[image]

For more information read  [RecyclerView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/main/java/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java) line no. line 4723